# PHP - How to use the same set of files in each subdirectory?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

You see how facebook works, like if my profile is 
www.facebook.com/myusername
then there is a specific index.php file and other lots of files that open when I open facebook.com/myusername.
Now I believe it is highly unlikely that Facebook copied the same files into each and every user's username directory.
How else would it work?

I'll be having many different users using the same application, i.e. the same set of files with minor changes in one or two files. Do I necessarily have to copy all the files into all the user directories each time?

I tried putting an index.php file in the subdirectory that contains this code:

```
<?php
require '../index.php';
?>
```

Now even though that runs the ../index.php file inside the subdirectory, but when the ../index.php file redirects to say another file named 'otherfile.php', then it gives a 404 not found error, because 'otherfile.php' is not present in the subdirectory, it is present in the parent directory.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: There is [PHP realpath()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php)

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: As Luschn said use apache mod_rewrite. Here is a tutorial, haven't read it all but looked good when glanced through. http://pixelcode.co.uk/tutorials/webmaster/clean-urls-with-mod_rewrite/